# Creating an alias for password less ssh

Tags: mac, bash, ssh

I have set-up password less ssh, but i can't make an alias . I guess the alias is executed with other rights.

Here I can connect without issue :

```
MacBook-Pro:~ romain$ ssh romain@169.254.33.98
Last login: Fri Aug  5 19:09:20 2016
Mac:~ romain$ echo "worked !"
-bash: !": event not found
Mac:~ romain$ exit
logout
Connection to 169.254.33.98 closed.
```

But when I create an alias :

```
MacBook-Pro:~ romain$ tail -n 1  ~/.bash_profile 
alias macair='ssh romai@169.254.33.98'
```

I can't connect:

```
MacBook-Pro:~ romain$ macair
Password:
Password:
Password:
Permission denied (publickey,keyboard-interactive).
MacBook-Pro:~ romain$
```

Maybe wrong conf on authorized keys :

```
MacBook-Pro:~ romain$ ls -l ~/.ssh/
total 32
-rw-------  1 romain  staff   784  5 aoû 19:00 authorized_keys
-rw-------  1 romain  staff  1675  5 aoû 18:56 id_rsa
-rw-r--r--@ 1 romain  staff   416  5 aoû 18:56 id_rsa.pub
-rw-r--r--  1 romain  staff  1850  1 aoû 16:40 known_hosts
```

Comment: your misspelt the username `alias macair='ssh romai@169.254.33.98'`  should be romain not romai

Comment: Your alias shows you logging in as user `romai` rather than `romain`.  Is this a typo in your question, or in your alias (which would cause the pubkey login to fail) ?

Comment: @user4556274  it should be romain obviously, as in his superuser name, and as in his command prompt and as in the name 'romain'

Comment: @barlop, yes, obviously.  The question was whether the error is *on his system* or only in his typing on this page.